# Measuring Distance Between Peaks

Tags: matlab

I have used the (findpeaks) function in Matlab,  in order to find the locations and the value of the peaks in the signal.

```
findpeaks(X_Segments{1});
```

X_Segments contains the data, here is sample of the figure that I got

[image: Find All Peaks in the signal]

As shown in the figure, some of the peaks are very close to each other, therefore, I'd to filter out these peaks (remove them) in order to have Peaks in the signal at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the parameter `MinPeakDistance` into the `findpeaks` function you can set the minimum distance between peaks. In your case:

```
findpeaks(X_Segments{1}, 'MinPeakDistance', 10);
```

Alternatively, you may find the `MinPeakProminence` or `threshold` parameters useful. See the examples [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html).

Comment: thank you so much mate, please if you don't mind me ask you another question, i'd like to measure  Time in milliseconds between
successive peaks and then calculate the average.

Comment: Look at getting `findpeaks` to return the indices of the peaks. Use these to determine the actual time-values of your peaks. You can then use the `diff` and `mean` functions to find the mean spacing. Looking at your data though, the peaks do not seem very evenly spaced. If you're struggling try asking a separate question (the comments section is not really the place to ask new questions!)